# Push View Controller by overriding shouldSelect method in TabbarViewController

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, tabbar, tabbarcontroller

I want to push a ViewController when an item in TabBar is selected I have written following code but it is not working

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if let ind = tabBarController.viewControllers!.index(of:viewController) , bottomBarTabsArray[ind].viewType == BottomBarInfo.VIEWTYPE_ASSISTANT { //
          let tabVC = AppStrings.appStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "assitantViewControllerID") as! AssitantViewController
        self.selectedViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabVC, animated: true)
         return false
     }
    return true
}
```

how to push ViewController when tabbar item is selected instead of switching to ViewController

Comment: navigation is nil `print(self.selectedViewController?.navigationController)` ??

Comment: yeah it is nil but I am assigning it self?.viewControllers =  listViewController.map{
                                return UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: $0)
                            }

Comment: oh got it already it is UINavigationController thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
self.selectedViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(tabVC, animated: true)
```

with

```
(self.selectedViewController as! UINavigationController ).pushViewController(tabVC, animated: true)
```